# Ordering by specific field value LIKE first

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I know the `ORDER BY FIELD(fieldname, value1, value2, ..., valueN)` function.

How could I order my results not by specific values, but by "like" values, if any?

Example:

This is the table1

```
--------------------
| ID | DESCRIPTION |
--------------------
| 1  | Hello       |    
| 2  | World       |
--------------------
```

I would like to order by `DESCRIPTION like 'Wo%'`, than the rest

In "pseudo code", something similar to:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY FIELD(DESCRIPTION, 'Wo%') DESC
```

Expected result is:

```
----------------
|  DESCRIPTION |
----------------
|  World       |    
|  Hello       |
----------------
```

This code doesn't work as `value1, ..., valueN` are expected to be exact field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use expressions in the ORDER BY clause,  for example:

```
 SELECT t.description
   FROM table1 t
  ORDER
     BY t.description LIKE 'Wo%' DESC 
      , t.description
```

The expression  `t.description LIKE 'Wo%'` is going to evaluate to 0, 1 or NULL.
So NULL values of `description` will sort last, values that satisfy the condition will sort first (because we've specified `DESC` for descending sort order.

The more portable, more ANSI-standards compliant equivalent would be:

```
 SELECT t.description
   FROM table1 t
  ORDER
     BY CASE WHEN t.description LIKE 'Wo%' THEN 1 
             WHEN t.description NOT LIKE 'Wo%' THEN 0 
        END DESC
      , t.description
```

---

If we could omit that second `WHEN` and just do `ELSE 0`, which would give us slightly different behavior with NULL values of `descrption`.

If we don't like the naked "foo LIKE bar" expression in the `ORDER BY` clause, we could wrap it in a MySQL function, to make it more clear to the future reader,

```
 SELECT t.description
   FROM table1 t
  ORDER
     BY IF(t.description LIKE 'Wo%',1,0) DESC
      , t.description
```

---

Again, the key point here is that we can use *expressions* in the `ORDER BY` clause. For testing, we can include that same expression in the SELECT list, so we can "see" (in the returned results) what those expressions are evaluating to. But note there isn't a requirement that the expressions in the `ORDER BY` have to appear in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1):

- You can calculate ranking in `Select` clause, as per your `LIKE%%` requirements. You can use [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function or [Case When](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) statement.
- In case of single `LIKE%%` requirements, [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) can be used, else [Case When](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).
- Now, you can order the result by that ranking.
- **Note:** [As answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52521506/2469308) by *@spencer7593*, you can do the same `CASE WHEN` in the `ORDER BY` clause itself, instead of calculating them explicitly in Select clause first.

Try the following:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, IF(DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Wo%', 1, 99999) AS Rank  
FROM table1 
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

In case of multiple `LIKE%%` conditions, you can use the following:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, 
       CASE 
         WHEN DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Wo%' THEN 1 
         WHEN DESCRIPTION LIKE '%He%' THEN 2 
         ELSE 99999
       END AS Rank  
FROM table1 
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

Comment: We can order by an expression that isn't in the SELECT list i.e. it's not necessary to return a derived column named rank in the resultset. We can just put the expression into the `ORDER BY` clause. For testing, yes, we may want to include the expression in the SELECT list, so we can "see" in the results what the expression evaluates to.

Comment: @spencer7593 I know that but I like to normally see the expression results on which I am ordering. From MySQL point of view, I don't think any performance difference is there. It has to first calculate the expression value in either case and then do the sorting. Only thing is data packet being fetched will be slightly larger. Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: no you're not wrong. It's just that the answer provided seems to imply that its only possible to to order by expressions that are in the SELECT list; doesn't give any indication that the CASE expression could be in the ORDER BY clause. (It may be obvious to you and I, but I'm not sure OP gets that understanding from this answer. My comment would be superfluous if this answer gave an example of an expression in just the ORDER BY without a a derived column in the SELECT list.)

Comment: And I agree with you about expressions in the SELECT list. I frequently do that, to test expressions that are going to go in a WHERE clause or an ORDER BY clause.  It is much easier to test and verify the evaluation of expressions when those are in a SELECT list, we can inspect the results returned.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks. I have updated the answer to refer your answer as well - in case someone is looking to do it directly in Order by clause.

Answer (score -1):

Try like

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION 
FROM table1 
Where DESCRIPTION like 'Wo%' 
order by DESCRIPTION.
```

Comment: This won't give the expected output. Check OP